# Cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'

Tags: linq

I'm trying to export a SQL query result to an CSV file, but i'm having some issues with the cast.

here's my code :

```
var query = string.Concat((from t in db.employees select t.ID + "," + t.LastName+"\n" ).Take(2000));

return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(query), "text/csv", "Report.csv");
```

But i have the following error : `Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.`

Can you help me on this ? Thanks

Comment: What EF version is this? The problem is the string formatting which EF embarrassingly fails to translate.

Comment: @usr It could be an old version of .NET without `string.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)`, so the chosen overload is `string.Concat(object)`

Comment: @DStanley EF does not understand that string.Concat(object) does that. This is a translation deficiency in EF. L2S does not have this problem.

Comment: Under .NET 4.5 and the latest EF this just works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to query the data and do the string projection in two steps:

```
var query = 
    (from t in db.employees 
     select new {t.ID , t.LastName})
    .Take(2000)
    .AsEnumerable();

var csv = string.Concat(query.Select(t => t.ID + "," + t.LastName + "\n"));

return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Report.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like EF is unable to translate your string concatenation call to SQL. You should be able to work around this issue by concatenating in memory:

```
var query = string.Concat(
    db.employees
        .Select(e => new {ID, LastName})
        .Take(2000)
        .AsEnumerable() // The rest of the query happens in memory
        .Select(p => p.ID + "," + p.LastName)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to post my theory:

```
var query = string.Concat(
    (from t in db.employees select t.ID + "," + t.LastName+"\n" )
    .Take(2000)
    .ToArray());
```

The difference is the final `.ToArray()`. `string.Concat(IEnumerable<string>)` was introduced in .NET 4.0 . Perhaps you are using an older version of .NET .